# Bash - how to run scl_devtool-9 and get the gcc --version output

Tags: bash, scripting

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
gcc --version
```

result:
devtoolset-9 is now enabled on the system, but I don't have the `gcc --version` output. gcc 9.x.x is installed. At the prompt when I type `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash`, the system runs devtoolset-9 and I can verify the gcc version by typing `gcc --version`.

How can I run the bash script and get the `gcc --version output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scl enable ...` command creates a new shell; you've probably ended up with several nested layers of shells if you've been testing this. If you `exit`, you'll probably see the `gcc --version` output from the base system. See how deeply-nested you are with something like `pstree -s $$`.

To run `gcc --version` with scl, just put the command on the `scl` line:

```
 scl enable devtoolset-9 'gcc --version'
```

Reference: [The Red Hat Developer Toolset 9 User Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/9/pdf/user_guide/red_hat_developer_toolset-9-user_guide-en-us.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: Thank you @jeffschaller, the script works perfectly well.  Indeed, each time i tried my script I always typedexit

Comment: If I need to run devtoolset-9 to run other commands within the script what command line would I use to exit from the devtoolset-9 once my script finish running  to go back to the default  gcc

Comment: Every time you run `scl enable devtoolset-9 'some command other than a shell'`, you'll return to the normal environment (default gcc). I think you're getting tripped up by entering an `scl ... bash` shell all the time.

Comment: Ok - I see. So, if I want to run scl enable devtoolset-9 and run some other shell command with devtoolset-9  how should I write the command lines?

Comment: Just like we did with `scl enable devtoolset-9 'gcc --version'`, right? `scl enable devtoolset-9 'make -v'` or `scl enable devtoolset-9 'date'`.

Comment: Great! Thank you @jeffschaller for your help with this. Would you say this script is correct and will run under devtoolset-9 environment? 

`#!/bin/bash 

scl enable devtoolset-9 
# 
export GTPLICENSE=12345 
cd /home/eric/data 
# 
# other commands ............ 
exit 
exit`

Answer (score 1):

to get the script to act as you want it to, you need the `scl` command to modify the current bash session rather than spawn a new one.

you can do it this way

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# switch to GCC9 environment for the duration of the script
source scl_source enable devtoolset-9

gcc --version
```